# Why redisTemplate.opsForValue().get() always not null?

Tags: java, redis

I use

> @Autowired private RedisTemplate < String, Object > redisTemplate;

and

> redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);

IDE gives me a warning telling the result always not null,

but I see the method V get(Object key) is marked as @Nullable and I think the V get(Object key) should return null when there is no such key exist.

[image]

Any idea for me, Thanks!